# Set aws tags and instance name with ec2 driver in test kitchen?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

Is there a way to set aws tags and an instance name with ec2 driver in test kitchen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's even [documented in the README](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-ec2#tags). Use the driver config key `tags`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the documentation does not make it overly clear for people new to Chef/Ruby. Here is a YAML sample from my .kitchen.yml file.

```
driver:
  name: ec2
  instance_type: t2.medium
  region: us-east-1
  security_group_ids:
    - sg-1234567abcd
  subnet_id: subnet-12345677
  tags:
    Name: 'test-kitchen WinCustomAMI'
    Environment: 'test'
    SN Project: 'Custom AMI'
    SN Platform: 'Windows 2012R2'
    SN Owner: 'Some Team'
```

Comment: An answer should contain more than a code snipped. Please provide more relevant explanation.

Comment: Yeah, the doc doesn't show examples. One large file with all the syntax used would really make life easy.

Answer (score 1):

Also I couldn't find this JSON way of doing it in the docs.

```
driver:
  name: ec2
  tags: {"Name": "my-first-ec2", "Contact": "me@mycompany.com"}
```